# How to change php executable used by CakePHP Console?

Tags: php, cakephp, php-5.4

I have in my customer server 2 apaches/php version.

So, the primary version `(/usr/bin/php)` is the old version, and other is the 5.4.17 `(/usr/bin/php54)`.

I verify the `app/Console/cake` file, and found the exec command. When I try change to `php54 -q .......` doesn't work.

**Doesn't work =** nothing happens. CakePHP console not appear, shell or tasks not run, but the console still freeze.

How can I do that? Or check the error generate by CakePHP console generated when I change the executable.

Thanks.

Comment: what means `doesn't work` ?

Comment: Doesn't work = nothing happens. CakePHP console not appear, shell or tasks not run, but the console still freeze.

Comment: You should verify app/tmp/logs, first.

Answer (score 0):

I solve that, removing the parameter `-q` after the `php54` executable.

```
exec php 54 "$CONSOLE"/cake.php -working "$APP" "$@"
```

I sincerely no have idea what this parameter do.

Comment: From [Command line options](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php): *Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP header output (CGI only).*